# Regular expressions using .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

```
value = value.replace('[b]', '');
value = value.replace('[/b]', '');
```

How can I optimize this code?

I have a feeling I can do it with a regular expression. Something like

```
value.replace('/^[\/?b]/', '');
```

but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]` in your regexp. Something like this: `/^\[b\][^[]+\[\/b\]/`. It's because they are matchcharacters. **Edit:** you don't need to quote when you want to use regexp in `.replace()` function. In fact,you aren't using regexp.

Comment: @The Mask Even after escaping them, it was unsuccessful.

Comment: There's no jQuery code here, I changed the tag to javascript.

Comment: @OP: See edit. You need to remove the quotes too or it will be only a normal string,not `RegExp`.

Comment: I really don't think you will get a huge increase in performance by combining those two statements. Leaving them as they are is far clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value = value.replace(/\[\/?b\]/g, '');
```

You need to escape the brackets and slash, and you don't put a regular expression inside quotes. And the `g` modifier is needed to replace all the occurrences.